# How can I implement a remote contact lookup in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Our company uses Exchange ActiveSync to remotely access contacts through the Contact application. Lookups by name work correctly, but lookups by phone number do not. Also, when an employee calls that isn't synced to the contact list that user information isn't displayed on the Phone application.

I'd like to create a better component to provide lookup of a user by phone number that should, hopefully, show their information when a phone call is received. I would like to keep the requests all remote and not perform a sync. It seems like the ActiveSync component does all its lookups remotely (is not synced) because if you put the phone in airplane mode the lookups don't work.

Can anyone point me to how this is done in Android? I've read about accounts, remote sync, and contact providers but it is not clear how to put these together to accomplish this - if this is even the right direction.